# How to check JAVA_OPTS value in command prompt?

Tags: java, jboss

Our application is deploy JBoss server then throws error PermGen space
Then java_OPTS in set permgen variable in jboss bat and config file.
JAVA_OPTs in value assige or not how to check it?
How to check JAVA_OPTS value in command prompt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if your JAVA_OPTS is set in Windows then with simple:

```
echo %JAVA_OPTS%
```

in linux

```
echo "$JAVA_OPTS"
```

but it is possible that it is set first in your standalone.bat file. Then its valid only for execution time of standalone.bat (.sh) file and you can find its value in this file.

hope i could help