# What are the default JVM options used by an akka/scala application?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a zip file generated from `dist` in IntelliJ.
After unzipping it, I have the following file tree:

```
D:.
├───bin
│       foo
│       foo.bat
│
└───lib
        a.jar
        b.jar
        com.foo.jar
        ...
        x.jar
```

In Windows, I'm able to run the `foo.bat` to execute the program.
But it seems to have some memory leak, causing following exception after running for ~12 hours:

```
Uncaught error from thread [dr-akka-ven-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5142] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[dr-akka-ven]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:622)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
        ......
```

**Question:** how do I know the JVM options being used (like `-Xms64m` and `-Xmx128m`), so that I can increase the memory to workaround the issue for now?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1441373/3380951

Comment: i've tried `echo %JAVA_OPTS%` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871694/3380951), but it simply returns `%JAVA_OPTS%`

Comment: What's in `foo.bat`?

Comment: @SethTisue here's the line which makes the call: `"%_JAVACMD%" !_JAVA_OPTS! !DR_AKKA_VEN_OPTS! -cp "%APP_CLASSPATH%" %MAIN_CLASS% !_APP_ARGS!`. I have skimmed the `bat` file, but could not figure out what values of `_JAVA_OPTS` are being used. I haven't have a Windows environment variable of that name.

Comment: modify the batch file to print it? maybe it's empty and you're just getting JVM defaults?